# Открытие ссылки в новой вкладке с помощью JS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, javascript

Всем добрый день.

Имеется следующий код, который срабатывает при событии клик:

```
var idzakaz = $(this).next('.idenzak').val();
var naklad = $(this).prev('.idnaklad').val();

window.open('?komplects='+idzakaz, '_blank');
window.open('?pechat='+naklad, '_blank');
```

Но возникает следующая проблема: при открытии второй ссылки в Google Сhrome она открывается не в новой вкладке, а в новом окне. Подскажите, как от этого избавиться и сделать так, чтобы обе ссылки открывались в новых вкладках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Был проект с подобным замечанием, который необходимо было исправить, т.к. желание клиента - закон.
Выход следующий: 
 1. Создаем html-element, по нажатию на который идет открытие нужной вам ссылки в новом окне. Элемент делаем скрытым.
 2. При помощи js эмулируем нажатие(submit) по этому html-элементу.

П.С. если ссылка динамическая, то сначало при помощи js устанавливаем ссылку, а потом эмулируем нажатие.

Answer (score 0):

Открытие ссылки в новом окне или вкладке - это настройка браузера текущего пользователя. И JS тут ничем рулить не может.